# Android: issue setting LinearLayout height programmatically

Tags: android

I'm trying to create a new LinearLayout from the activity to insert it in another view and that's how i do it

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
linearLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.color.customBlue);
linearLayout.getLayoutParams().height= ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
linearLayout.getLayoutParams().width= ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
```

But I get this error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to write to field 'int
android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams.height' on a null object reference
```

So how can I set LinearLayout width and height to match_parent or wrap_content programmatically? what's the mistake here?

Answer (score 0):

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
linearLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong, you are trying to set a null layout param height because you haven't set the layout param to the LinearLayout after creating the layout object.

```
LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL); 
ll.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

`